# Toggle between .on() and .off() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function toggleExpansion(actions){
   if(actions === 'on') {
    $('.left-column').on('click', expand);
  }
  if(actions === 'off') {
    $('.left-column').off('click', expand);
  }
}
```

I will be calling `toggleExpansion('on')` or `toggleExpansion('off')` multiple times.

I want to rewrite toggleExpansion such that it would behave the same but with lesser code :

```
function toggleExpansion(actions){
    $('.left-column').actions('click', expand);
}
```

Obviously jquery does not know if I am referring to the variable `actions` or looking for a method called `action()`. If I use:

```
 function toggleExpansion(actions){
        $('.left-column').(actions.valueOf)('click', expand);
    }
```

it evaluates to `$('.left-column').(on)('click', expand)` which is wrong syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call a function that is a property of an object by name using `[]` syntax:

```
$('.left-column')[actions]('click', expand);
```

Comment: You're missing parenthisis; `'foo'.valueOf; // function valueOf() { [native code] }`, also `'foo'.valueOf() === 'foo'`

Comment: Thanks! This worked. We both forgot the parenthesis in front of valueOf(). Using [actions.valueOf()] or [actions] works great.

Comment: @PaulS. I was assuming that the OP was accessing for a property of that name, not invoking a function ;-)